# Thymeleaf problem with Java, Spring and Maven Project. It doesn't display in the browser.Doesn't connect with the controller.Cannot resolve customer

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

[Problem in Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWOOe.jpg)

[Thymeleaf plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWxq4.jpg)

[Plugins Spring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuvcb.jpg)

[this is image of an HTML document in IntelliJ IDEA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gO6Ja.jpg)

I receive a "Cannot resolve 'customer' " message in html document when I want to add some
`th:text = "customers.get(0).getFirstName()"`
or when I try any `th` tag. They don't work.

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {
   public List<Customer> customers;

   public HomeController(){
       this.customers = new ArrayList<>();
   }
    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public String addCustomer(@RequestParam String first, @RequestParam String last) {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setFirstName(first);
        customer.setLastName(last);
        customerRepository.save(customer);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public Iterable<Customer> getCustomer() {
        return customerRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/find/{id}")
    public Customer findCustomerById(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        return customerRepository.findCustomerById(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public ModelAndView home(ModelAndView modelAndView,Customer customer){
        customer.setFirstName("John");
        customer.setLastName("Smith");
        customer.setId(37);
        customers.add(customer);
        modelAndView.setViewName("home");
        modelAndView.addObject("customers",customers);
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

This is the HTML document that I was talking about. I will also show you my pom.xml file because I don't know where the problem might be.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="homeStyle.css">
</head>

<body>
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">List</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

</header>


<main>


    <tr th:each="customer : ${customers}">
        <td th:text="${customer.getFirstName()}"></td>
        <td th:text="${customer.getLastName()}"></td>
    </tr>


</main>

<footer>


</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my pom.xml with all dependencies needed I believe.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-tutorial</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-tutorial</name>
    <description>spring-boot-tutorial</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>18</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.15.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: "_in html document_" - what HTML document? You can [edit] the question to show us.

Comment: [Thymeleaf expressions](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#variables) are created using `${...}`.

Comment: Sorry I thought I can't place more code here.

Comment: Ohh also it doesn't work with or without "www." in front of thymeleaf.org

Comment: Your error is caused by a typo. Your Java is `modelAndView.addObject("customers",customers);` but in your Thymeleaf you are using `<tr th:each="customer : ${customer}">`. It should be `<tr th:each="customer : ${customers}">`.

Comment: Also, just as an enhancement, you should be able to replace `${customer.getFirstName()}` with just `${customer.firstName}` - use the property and Thymeleaf will call the getter for you (assuming you are following JavaBean naming conventions correctly).

Comment: Sorry I did that by mistake, I made a lot of changes to figure it out, but I still can't. It is not from that typo, I believe it must be something fundamental that I am missing. May be something in the properties of Intellij IDEA , but I don't know what might be. The plugin for Thymeleaf is on and for Spring and Spring Initializer.

Comment: I will add a screenshot on top of the post

Comment: Is there problem with my pom.xml?
Am I missing some dependencies or is there a problem with 
  spring-boot-starter-parent version 2.7.3  and thymeleaf 3.0.15.RELEASE

Comment: Or I have to make some configurations to my Intellij IDEA, should I try Eclipse